# How to map over an ImmutableJS List of Maps in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I've got an ImmutableJS structure in a Redux store looking like this:

```
Immutable.fromJS([{
  foo: 'bar'
}, {
  foo: 'baz'
}]);
```

It's being mapped to this.props.items in my React component. In my React render function I'm trying to do this:

```
this.props.items.map(item => {
  return (
    <div>{item.foo}</div>
  );
});
```

Nothing is being rendered. However if I `.toJS()` the list as below then it works:

```
this.props.items.toJS().map(item => {
  return (
    <div>{item.foo}</div>
  );
});
```

My question is: is .toJS() the correct way to do this? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you replace `item.foo` with `item.get('foo')`, you should be good to go. The function `Immutable.fromJS` does a deep convert to an immutable structure.